# How to rotate rectangle?

Tags: java, graphics2d, rectangles, affinetransform

Here is an example of drawing the left leg of my character:

```
g2d.fillRect(pX + (headW - bodyW)/2, pY + headH + bodyH, legW, legH); //left leg
```

I know how to rotate images with `AffineTransform`s, like this:

```
AffineTransform tr = g2d.getTransform();
tr.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotAmount));
g2d.drawImage(playerI, tr, null);
```

How can I rotate this rectangle with an `AffineTransform`? I can't do something like:

```
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotAmount));
```

Because that rotates my entire person. How can I rotate only the leg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found out how.

```
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(lLegRot));
g2d.fillRect(pX + (headW - bodyW)/2, pY + headH + bodyH, legW, legH); //left leg
g2d.setTransform(old);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rLegRot));
g2d.fillRect(pX + headW - legW - (headW - bodyW)/2, pY + headH + bodyH, legW, legH); //right leg
```

Newer rotations override older ones while keeping the previously rotated thing intact. To reset rotation just do `g2d.setTransform(old);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use java.awt.geom you can make that with rotate(someAngle) method.